# Start with previous page in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

It always starting with previous page where exception occurred.  example I got an exception or error on `http://local.company.com:55253/Views/Staff/Index.cshtml`. If correct and run the project in visual studio, url open with `http://local.company.com:55253/Views/Staff/Index.cshtml`. It is suppose to start with `http://local.company.com:55253/`

Any settings needs to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define which url to start at by right clicking your web-project -> properties -> Web.

Instead of using "Current page", choose "Specific page" and enter the URL you would like to start at.